# matches method is not returning true

Tags: java, regex

```
package com.wynd.service.response;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a = "http://localhost:8001/eWS/sales/users/C12562/sites";
        System.out.println(a.matches("([/sales/users/][0-9A-Za-z][/sites])"));  
    }
}
```

I need matches method should return true. What should be the regex. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

when you put something in brackets, it means that you are searching for single character in the range defined in brackets.

Your string is matched with: `.*/sales/users/[0-9A-Za-z]+/sites`
For non java string matching "/" needs to me escaped with "\".

References:

`[a-zA-Z]` - Matches any characters between a-z or A-Z. You can combine as much as you please.

`.` - Matches any character other than newline (or including newline with the /s flag)

`a*` - Matches zero or more consecutive `a` characters (in this case .)

Comment: `/` should not be escaped, it is not any special in a Java string regex pattern. Regex101 does not support Java regex flavor, although outputs Java code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the info Wiktor, comment is edited accordingly.